# what is this protrusion on one side of my platform pedal for?

Tags: pedals

I've bought new pedals like on the picture. They are good, but i'm confused about the part, marked on the picture.

I've always thought that pedals have no 'up' and 'down' sides, so i can't realize why it's assymetric.
[image]

Can you explain me the use of the marked part?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you fit toe clips to your pedals, that spike is there to help you flip the pedal over so the clip is on the top.

The pedals have an up and down orientation when toeclips are fitted.

[image]

Comment: thanks! btw: are those clips realy useful?

Comment: Before (the incredibly misnamed) "clipless" pedals, toe straps/clips were enormously important.  Now pretty much anyone who would use toe straps instead goes "clipless".

Comment: @DanielRHicks In the urban subculture, some bikers prefer to use toestraps so that they can use any kind of shoe. This makes some sense, specially for fixers who need the straps to control the speed of the bike. That's fashion meeting functionality! ;oP

Comment: I still prefer clips and straps on my mtn and road bikes.  I am not a racer and they are much simpler to maintain.