# Role of the part situated below the pedals?

Tags: road-bike, pedals

I'm wondering what's the role of the plastic/metallic part situated below the pedals on the image below taken from a road bike?

[image: Road bike pedals]

Comment: This https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/9800/what-is-this-protrusion-on-one-side-of-my-platform-pedal-for is related I think - so this part is to hold your leg on the pedal

Comment: Sidenote, the clip isn't supposed to be on the bottom of the pedal, in case @Paparazii's answer didn't make it clear.

Comment: Commenting - I had one of these catch a root or something while riding a MTB up a slope.  The bike stopped real quick - I didn't.   So put your toe in it while riding, or take it off completely and fit a pedal reflector instead.

Comment: How do you remove it? the screws seems to be in the inside and the `pedal reflector` is like the one in this link [Pedal reflectors](https://www.athleteshop.co.uk/contec-reflectors-pedal)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a toe clip but it is missing the strap.
[image]

Add a strap or remove the toe clip.

For the most part they have been replace by clipless pedals.  That is why clipless is called clipless as there is no toe clip.

Comment: You should either remove it or install a strap because it will be insecure when used in the present manner, risk of catching the rear of the trouser leg at the ankle when putting the foot down at a stop.

Comment: A strap would be useful but it isn't necessarily "missing". Some bikes come like that new.   You don't get all the advantages of a clip but it's much easier to use and still stops your foot going too far forward.

Comment: @Niall Do you have a citation on that?

Comment: Just a note to the original poster, "clipless" pedals aren't what they might sound like. They aren't the simple traditional platform pedals that also don't have toe clips. They're pedals that attach to a cleat on special shoes worn by the rider.

Comment: @Paparazzi search for 'half toe clip' or 'strapless toe clip' for the ones designed without a strap, but the OP's image is a normal one with the strap missing.